# event detection between different controls vb

Tags: vb.net, oop

I have a class A which contains 2 user controls  declared as

```
Friend WithEvents CustInfo1 As WindowsApplication1.CustInfo
Friend WithEvents ServiceLocation1 As WindowsApplication1.ServiceLocation
```

Both have textBoxes. If value of textBoxA in custInfo1 changes then how can I make value of textBoxB in SeviceLocation1 also change

I will be most thankful if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to catch the event from your CustInfo control and then call some method on the ServiceLocation control. (You might have to create your own "changed" events in your control.)

Comment: is it possible to call a function in class A from the custInfo contol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Inside the CustInfo user control, you need to write code inside the textBoxA Changed event that raises an event from the CustInfo user control  (e.g. TextBoxChanged event). [RaiseEvent statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. Inside the ServiceLocation user control, create a public property getter and setter for whatever your textBoxB.Text is
3. On the form that contains both user controls, create code in the new CustInfo TextBoxChanged event and set the new property on the ServiceLocation1 user control.

Answer (score 0):

All controls (also custom controls) have the property [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx), through which you can access the (sub) controls of that control. Now you can retrieve your textbox by calling the `.Item(key)` method on it. Then you can assign a event handler to it in your form or class.

```
Dim key As String = "textBoxA" 'Or simply the name of that TextBox in your CustInfo
Dim textboxA As TextBox = CustInfo1.Controls.Item(key)
AddHandler textBoxA.TextChanged, AddressOf mytextchangedhandler
```

Where that `mytextchangedhandler` handles the TextChanged event for that TextBox.

Personally I don't like this method too much, as you are relying on knowing either the name of the TextBox or the index in the Controls list of your usercontrol.

I would definitely go for the option to create your own event on your usercontrol. It is quite easy to do even! Below how to do it. In the code behind of your usercontrol, you'll have to add an event declaration:

```
Event MyTextBoxChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Now we'll have to raise it, we do this by implementing the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBoxA` in your usercontrol (as you explained you wanted to do):

```
Private Sub TextBoxA_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxA.TextChanged
    RaiseEvent MyTextBoxChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Now we can simply implement this event (`MyTextBoxChanged`) in your Form as follows:

```
Private Sub CustInfo1_MyTextBoxChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CustInfo1.MyTextBoxChanged
    ' Do something
End Sub
```

Obviously we still need to get the updated text, now we can create our own EventArgs that will give us the new (and/or old value) as you will want to have. We simply can inherit the `System.EventArgs` class and add some properties (for example a property `OldText` that holds the old text value and a property `NewText` that holds the new text value):

```
Public Class MyEventArgs
    Inherits System.EventArgs

    Private _OldText As String
    Public ReadOnly Property OldText() As String
        Get
            Return _OldText
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _NewText As String
    Public ReadOnly Property NewText() As String
        Get
            Return _NewText
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(oldText As String, newText As String)
        _OldText = oldText
        _NewText = newText
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now we have to change the event definition and raising to use the `MyEventArgs`:

```
Event MyTextBoxChanged(sender As Object, e As MyEventArgs)

Private Sub TextBoxA_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxA.TextChanged
    RaiseEvent MyTextBoxChanged(Me, New MyEventArgs(TextBoxA.Text))
End Sub
```

And also change the implementation in your Form:

```
Private Sub CustInfo1_MyTextBoxChanged(sender As System.Object, e As MyEventArgs) Handles CustInfo1.MyTextBoxChanged
    MessageBox.Show(e.Text)
End Sub
```

More information about events can be found on our favorite spot [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx).